# KeyError exception while reading a GraphML file with NetworkX occurs in Visual Studio 2017 but not Spyder

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017, networkx, graphml

I am attempting to read a GraphML file using the NetworkX Python package in Visual Studio 2017 Community, using the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
import glob
import re

data = {}
graphs = {}

for graphml in glob.glob("*.graphml"):
    m = re.match(r'^ant_mersch_col([0-9]+)_day([0-9]+)_attribute.graphml$', graphml).groups()

    if m[0] not in data.keys():
        data[m[0]] = []
        graphs[m[0]] = {}

    data[m[0]].append(m[1])

    graphs[m[0]][m[1]] = nx.read_graphml(graphml)
```

I've omitted most of the nodes and edges for brevity, but here's the abbreviated GraphML file I'm trying to read:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd"><key id="d16" for="edge" attr.name="weight" attr.type="long"/>
<key id="d15" for="node" attr.name="nb_interaction_queen" attr.type="double"/>
<key id="d14" for="node" attr.name="nb_interaction_foragers" attr.type="double"/>
<key id="d13" for="node" attr.name="nb_interaction_cleaners" attr.type="double"/>
<key id="d12" for="node" attr.name="nb_interaction_nurses" attr.type="double"/>
<key id="d11" for="node" attr.name="visits_to_rubbishpile" attr.type="double"/>
<key id="d10" for="node" attr.name="visits_to_nest_entrance" attr.type="double"/>
<key id="d9" for="node" attr.name="visits_to_brood" attr.type="double"/>
<key id="d8" for="node" attr.name="group_period4" attr.type="string"/>
<key id="d7" for="node" attr.name="group_period3" attr.type="string"/>
<key id="d6" for="node" attr.name="group_period2" attr.type="string"/>
<key id="d5" for="node" attr.name="group_period1" attr.type="string"/>
<key id="d4" for="node" attr.name="nb_foraging_events" attr.type="long"/>
<key id="d3" for="node" attr.name="age(days)" attr.type="long"/>
<key id="d2" for="node" attr.name="body_size" attr.type="double"/>
<key id="d1" for="node" attr.name="tag_id" attr.type="long"/>
<key id="d0" for="node" attr.name="colony" attr.type="long"/>
<graph edgedefault="undirected">
<node id="Ant620">
  <data key="d0">4</data>
  <data key="d1">620</data>
  <data key="d2">141.45</data>
  <data key="d3">57</data>
  <data key="d4">0</data>
  <data key="d5">N</data>
  <data key="d6">C</data>
  <data key="d7"> </data>
  <data key="d8"> </data>
  <data key="d9">137.909</data>
  <data key="d10">0.909091</data>
  <data key="d11">4.63636</data>
  <data key="d12">161.63636</data>
  <data key="d13">169.36364</data>
  <data key="d14">68.363636</data>
  <data key="d15">8.636000000000001</data>
</node>
<edge source="Ant347" target="Ant186">
  <data key="d16">2</data>
</edge>
</graph>
</graphml>
```

The file, by the way, is ant data from Network Repository; the full file can be found [here](http://networkrepository.com/insecta-ant-colony4.php) for those that are curious.

I get the rather ambiguous exception `'long'` in my IDE, which is apparently a `KeyError` based on the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 119, in <module>
    
vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, run_as)

  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\debugger.py", line 37, in debug
    
run(address, filename, *args, **kwargs)

  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_local.py", line 64, in run_file
    
run(argv, addr, **kwargs)

  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_local.py", line 125, in _run
    
_pydevd.main()

  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1752, in main
    
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)

  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1099, in run
    
return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)

  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1106, in _exec
    
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script

  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:\Users\Ethan_000\Source\Repos\Research\Research\Ants.py", line 22, in <module>
    
nx.read_graphml(graphml)

  File "<decorator-gen-692>", line 2, in read_graphml
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py", line 239, in _open_file
    
result = func_to_be_decorated(*new_args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\graphml.py", line 258, in read_graphml
    
glist = list(reader(path=path))

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\graphml.py", line 775, in __call__
    
(keys, defaults) = self.find_graphml_keys(self.xml)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\graphml.py", line 951, in find_graphml_keys
    
"type": self.python_type[attr_type],

KeyError
: 
'long'
```

The weird thing is that this does *not* occur when I run almost identical code in Spyder.

Does anyone know why this might occur in Visual Studio 2017 (but *not* in Spyder) and how I could fix it?